# Could you do a query with subqueries like this with nhibernate?

Tags: sql, nhibernate

If you had a query that looks like this, could it be converted into a nhibernate query?

```
SELECT ....
FROM
(
   SELECT ...
   FROM ...
   GROUP BY...
   ORDER BY ...

   UNION

   SELECT ..
   FROM ...
)
AS ASDF
GROUP BY ...
ORDER BY ...
```

Answer (score 0):

With hibernate you can do native SQL queries. You just need to create a named Sql query mapping, and map it to a class.

However, you will not get the benefit of writing to the named query. [Which is to be expected]

Answer (score 0):

if by "nhibernate query" you mean to use any non-sql method to express an sql query, like using `HQL` or the `ICriteria` api, no you wouldn't be able to use the `union` or to express a result set using `select * FROM ( select ... ) as FOO`

The named query that monksy refers to is writing an SQL-query that you bind to the mapping but you cannot manipulate that query in many ways